# Why are some verbs in the present tense, while others are in the past tense, at the beggining of bullet points in this resume?

Tags: tense, formal-language

The following is a part of a sample resume from [an article on Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/articles/software-engineer-resume). My qeustion is, why are some verbs in the present tense, while others are in the past tense, at the beggining of bullet points?:

> Senior Software Engineer, Ashton-Tate - Sept. 2020 - Jul. 2023
>
> - **Lead** and **participate** in the design, development, and implementation of three new software projects, adhering to best practices, coding standards, and architectural guidelines.
> - **Collaborated** with cross-functional teams, including product managers, designers, and other engineers, to define project scope, requirements, and timelines.
> - **Mentor** and **guided** a team of five junior developers, providing technical expertise, code reviews, and constructive feedback to foster their professional growth.
>
> Software Engineer, Al.Work — May 2018 - Sept. 2020
>
> - **Design**, **develop**, **test**, and **maintain** software solutions according to established coding standards and best practices.
> - **Debugged** and **troubleshot** software issues, identifying root causes and implementing timely solutions.

Comment: And this does matter, especially in a software engineering resume. When I run across such errors in resumes, I try to overlook them if the applicant is not a native English speaker, and I try to remind myself that they're applying to write code, not prose. But syntax and attention to detail matter greatly in coding, and if I think they ought to know better, it definitely serves as a red flag: If they can't be troubled to search closely for small errors in their resume, perhaps they'll show similar carelessness in their code (where a single misplaced comma breaks things!).

Comment: I can't find the "Senior Software Engineer" resume on that website. Perhaps they replaced it when someone realized how badly-written it was. Whatever - without *at least one example* we can actually read *in context*, I think the question is pointless.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I find it halfway down the page. (Meanwhile, off-topic, I would also criticize this example for being too vague. This is supposed to be the example for the highly experienced senior applicant, but aside from leadership, everything here should also be true for juniors. Don't waste time telling me that you "adhered to best practices." I hope that goes without saying. Please give me concrete, specific examples of what you accomplished.) In short: there is much better resume advice out there than this Coursera page. Keep looking, you can do better!

Comment: @AndyBonner: oic - it's the whimsically-titled "Babbage" example. Not much use for a site like this, because that resume is an ***image***, rather than searchable text. It's such tiny lettering I can barely make it out anyway, and things will be even worse for blind or partially-sighted people. For a website that's supposed to be all about "accurate, well-presented information", they obviously don't practice what they preach! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bad example. Wherever possible, you should use *parallel structure* in text with repeated elements like lists or resumes. You should ideally use the same tense, voice, and format for each entry in the resume. I would put all the verbs in the past tense.

This example is particularly sloppy in that it doesn't even use a consistent tense *within* bullets ("mentor and guided a team"), much less *across* the bullets.

Comment: The lack of parallelism stems from STEM thinking: I'm doing this now, I did that stuff then. But from the new employer's perspective, you will have done all that in the past - when you work for them. That's why all verbs of accomplishments on the resume are in the past.